# Swift - search controller keeps crashing

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

I am just starting to learn to swift; I want to add a search bar that allows users to search through the data in my Firebase database. The search bar has added but the code to filter the search result keeps crashing with this error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

The error is pointing to this line

`self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.businessArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       

    ref =  FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL:"")


    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar



    ref.child("Businesses").queryOrdered(byChild: "Basic-Info/business").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        //insert the rows
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.businessArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }


}
```

Comment: You need to add an object to your `businessArray` before you call `insertRows`

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting the rows in the table view you have to insert the items at the same indexes into the data source array.

However in this case I'd recommend to assign the query result to the data source array and call `reloadData()`

Comment: please how exactly will I do that, is there a way you can provide code sample

Comment: I'm not familiar with `FireBase`, but the returned `snapshot` is supposed to contain the filtered items. Assign the array to `businessArray` and call `reloadData()` on the table view.

Answer (score 0):

As @vadian said, you have to modify your datasource to match what you are trying to reflect in the UI. So if we are inserting a row into a `UITableView`, then you must **first** insert an object into the datasource *at the same index* of the row you are adding. Like so:

```
// First modify datasource
let businessObjectToInsert = BusinessObject() // or whatever your class is
self.businessArray.append(businessObject)

// Then insert row into `UITableView`
self.tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.businessArray.count-1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
```